# Regex for a serial number in T-SQL

Tags: sql-server, regex, sql-server-2005, t-sql, ssms

I'm a novice at regexs and am currently trying to come up with a simple regex that searches for a serial number in the following format: **0217103200XX**, where "XX" can each be a numeric digit.  I'm using SQL Server Management Studio to pass the regex as a parameter in a stored procedure.  I'm not sure if the syntax is any different from other programming languages.  I have the following regex as a reference:
**(?:2328\d\d(?:0[1-9]|[1-4]\d|5[0-3])\d{4})**

Any suggestions are appreciated.

UPDATE:
I'm actually using this in a SQL Query and not in a .Net application.  The format is as follows:

```
USE [MyDB]

EXEC MyStoredProcedure @regex = '(?:2328\d\d(?:0[1-9]|[1-4]\d|5[0-3])\d{4})'
```

Comment: SQL Server doesn't have native regex support - you need to have created a SQLCLR assembly to expose the functionality via .NET.

Comment: @OMG: There is also xp_pcre (see this [old answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/267921/) of me). Maybe a bit outdated nowadays, but works very well on one of our servers.

Comment: @Tomalak: Cool, but it's not native

Comment: @OMG Ponies: Well, depends on how you define "native". Extended stored procedures that are tied in via an external DLL are very well "native" to SQL server. ;-)

Comment: @Tomalak: That's what SQLCLR is too, basically. "native" to me means instantly available, doesn't require me to create something, load assembly/create SP, etc before I can do what I need to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As OMG Ponies stated - SQL Server does not natively support regex (need to use SQLCLR for 2005+, or xp_cre).

If I have understood your question, you could use a `PATINDEX` to find the serial numbers

```
Select *
From dbo.MyTable
Where PATINDEX('0217103200[0-9][0-9]', SerialNumberColumn) > 0
```

Comment: @gbn - No reason what so ever, I just like using PATINDEX.  Must be the brackets or something ;-)

Comment: Thanks for enlightening me.  I wasn't familiar enough with SQL Server to know whether or not RegExs were supported.  After looking at the stored procedure, it looks like the regex parameter is simply being inserted into the database for reference.

Answer (score 1):

Use LIKE: there is no native RegEx in SQL Server

```
LIKE '0217103200[0-9][0-9]'
```