# MySQL REGEXP to SQL Server

Tags: sql, mysql, sql-server, regex

What is the SQL Server equivalent of the MySQL expression below?

```
... WHERE somefield REGEXP '^[[:blank:]]*ASD[[:blank:]]*$|^[[:blank:]]*ASD[[:blank:]]*[[.vertical-line.]]|[[.vertical-line.]][[:blank:]]*ASD[[:blank:]]*$|[[.vertical-line.]][[:blank:]]*ASD[[:blank:]]*[[.vertical-line.]]'
```

Comment: Check this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/267921/regular-expressions-in-sql-server-servers Hope this helps.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Regular Expressions in SQL Server servers?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/267921/regular-expressions-in-sql-server-servers)

Comment: I'm not specifically looking for regular expressions in MSSQL, I just want any equivalent expression.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately the regex support in mssql is dreadful, the closest operator is "like" which misses out on the functionality of regex's by a mile.  You would have to look at breaking the regex up into multiple like statements and probably doing some dirty string manipulation to emulate what you are attempting to achieve.

For example while we could replicate the [[:blank:]] with [  ] (read [ Space Tab ]) we cant force matching zero or more of them, so instead we have to strip them out of the expression but this would match '  A S D ' so we need to test for the presence of ASD in the unmodified string.

I think the following would replace your regex but it was thrown together quickly so test it carefully.

```
replace(replace(somefield,' ',''),' ','') in ('ASD','|ASD','|ASD|','ASD|')
and
somefield like '%ASD%'
```

Again in my replace statements one is a space the other a tab.