# mysql REGEXP in MS sql server

Tags: mysql, sql-server, regex

I am migrating from mysql to MS SQL server. I need to re-factor the below query to be compatible with sql server

```
SELECT email 
FROM emailexcursions 
WHERE email NOT REGEXP '^[_A-Za-z0-9-]+(\.[_A-Za-z0-9-]+)*@[A-Za-z0-9-]+(\.[A-Za-z0-9-]+)*((\.[A-Za-z]{2,}){1}$)'
```

REGEXP is not available in sql server, does anyone know a workaround for this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4105897/mysql-regexp-to-sql-server

Answer (score 0):

You may write external function in C#/DLL and implement REGEXP there. BUT it is better to check the email before storing in DB.