# Need a Regular Expression that replaces all duplicate whitespace -next to each other- with a single whitepsace

Tags: regex

I have a simple piece of script (which uses RegEx) which cleans up a source string to leave only **alpha-numeric-and-whitespace** characters.

Sometimes, I end up with a number of whitespace characters next to each other.

eg.

```
source: abc def ghi 
result: abc def ghi

source: a*bc D*f
result: abc df

source: a*bc *** def
result: abc  def  <-- notice the two spaces in there
expected result: abc def  <-- notice one space, here.
```

So i was hoping some regex could look for **2+ spaces next to each other**, in some source string and **replace it with a single whitespace character**.

cheers :)

Comment: Sql Server 2008 unfortunately ... and I think I just found it it doesn't handle RegEx :(

Comment: Not *natively* anyhow: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/267921/regular-expressions-in-sql-server-servers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use `\s\s+` as the string to match, and a single space as the replacement.

Answer (score 1):

In C# this would be:

```
Regex regex = new Regex("\\s\\s+");
string output = regex.Replace(input, " ");
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a quick JavaScript function.  This does all whitespace, not just spaces.

```
function stripExtraSpaces(text)
{
   var exp = new RegExp("[\\s]+","g");
   return text.replace(exp," ");
}
```