# SQL Function to Munge a String

Tags: sql, sql-server, string, sql-server-2008

I need a function to convert a string into only alphanumeric characters...

Meaning replace (empty) all other characters besides the standard 26 letters and 10 numbers with nothing/blank.  And replace all spaces with a hyphen.  An example would be like this:

From

```
   stack## overfl*w's s"te !s cool!
```

To

```
   stack-overflws-ste-s-cool
```

Any Suggestions?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/267921/regular-expressions-in-sql-server-servers

Comment: Can you clarify if you want to keep hyphens? E.g. what result do you want if the input contains both hyphens and spaces, such as `'happy-go lucky'`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.StripNonAlphaNumerics
    (
      @s VARCHAR(255)
    )
    RETURNS VARCHAR(255)
    AS
    BEGIN
      DECLARE @p INT = 1, @n VARCHAR(255) = '', @c CHAR(1);
      SET @s = REPLACE(@s, ' ', '-');
      WHILE @p <= LEN(@s)
      BEGIN
        SET @c = SUBSTRING(@s, @p, 1);
        IF @c = '-' OR @c LIKE '[A-Za-z0-9]'
        BEGIN
          SET @n += @c;
        END 
        SET @p += 1;
      END
      RETURN(@n);
    END
    GO
```

Usage:

```
SELECT dbo.StripNonAlphaNumerics('tether-45(;$&@- ip');
```

Result:

```
tether-45--ip
```

Comment: best answer for completeness and understandability.

Answer (score 2):

You can use "the XML concatenation trick" for this. You'll need to have a table of integers from 1 to the length of the longest input string.

```
-- The table Nums should have a column "n" with
-- integers from 1 to N, where N is at least as long as
-- the longest input string.

declare @T table (
  id int,
  s varchar(40)
);

insert into @T values
  (1,'This *9--St ring.. '),
  (2,'@#_that*8.3a--String..')        
     select
      id,
      (
        select case when substring(s,n,1) = space(1) then '-' else substring(s,n,1) end
        from Nums
        where substring(s,n,1) like '[ a-zA-Z0-9]'
        and n between 1 and datalength(s)
        order by n
        for xml path('')
      ) as S
    from @T

Result:

id  S
1   This-9St-ring-
2   that83aString
```

Comment: +1 Steve, much nicer than my typical go-to loop. However your query doesn't deal with converting spaces to dashes.

Comment: Thanks, Aaron. Silly me for not reading the question, but I fixed the query to take care of this. (Changed LEN to DATALENGTH to take care of trailing spaces, as well.)

Answer (score 1):

You could employ the "character walker" concept, where you join each character of your original string to a table of sequential integers. In this example we limit the max length to 80, but you could of course make the integer table as large as needed.

```
declare @c table (i int);
declare @i int=1;
while @i<80 begin
    insert into @c values(@i);
    set @i+=1;
end

declare @str varchar(80)='stack## overfl*w''s s"te !s cool!';
declare @newstr varchar(80)='';

select @newstr+=replace(substring(@str,i,1),' ','-')
from @c
where substring(@str,i,1) like '[A-Za-z0-9 ]';

select @newstr;
```

Result:

```
stack-overflws-ste-s-cool
```

Performance note: This method is one I use in a function at work for cleaning bad characters from legacy data in conversion projects. In that setting, the integer table is created in advance and called by the function. The integer table's `i int` column also has a PK defined on it. Performance is remarkably fast.

Comment: Absolutely, just tested in SQL 08.