# REGEXP in SQL-Server-2008

Tags: mysql, regex, sql-server-2008, migration

I try to do a migration from MYSQL to SQL Server 2008 but i have a small problem.

I have this query:

```
SELECT SUM(duree) AS 'TotDuree'
FROM `mp3s`
WHERE `dirname` REGEXP CONVERT(_utf8 '$container_dir' USING latin1)
```

When i try to change it, i always have a problem with REGEXP. I made some search about it and someone said that we can't use REGEXP in SQL Server 2008.

I tried to find another way to do it but i didn't success.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might take a look at [**`PATINDEX`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188395.aspx).  See also these [related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/194652/sql-server-regular-expressions-in-t-sql) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/267921/regular-expressions-in-sql-server-servers).