# MSSQL pattern to match all numbers between [1-999]

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, pattern-matching

I want a SQL pattern expression to match all numbers between **1** and **999**.

**EDIT:**

In MSSQL.

Comment: Not all DBMs follow the same standard in regards to patterns and wildcard searches. You need to be specific. Initially your question did not have the right tags either.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

When using the LIKE operator pattern-matching in SQL for a character class, there's no wildcard repeat of the character class like there is in regex. In other words, you can't do things like `[0-9]+` or `[0-9]{1,3}` (both of these would also capture `0`)

So, you have to zero-pad the number before you can compare it.

It's not directly a *pattern*, but this *expression* relies in part on the LIKE operator and will work for positive integers between 1 and 999:

```
RIGHT('00' + myfield, 3) LIKE '[0-9][0-9][0-9]'
AND RIGHT('00' + myfield, 3) <> '000'
AND LEN(myfield) <= 3
```

Edit: assumption made that you're talking about Microsoft SQL Server, since you didn't specify.

Comment: In which DBMS will `LIKE '[0-9][0-9][0-9]'` work? It sure isn't a standard SQL `LIKE` wildcard (standard SQL only understands `%`and `_` wildcards, no "ranges")

Comment: Although not all but some do support regex to a great extent. In MySQL you could write `WHERE num REGEXP '^[1-9][0-9]{1,2}$'

Comment: @Hameed: I understand that, but your example did not use the `LIKE` operator.

Comment: @a_horse I was addressing the answer "there's no wildcard repeat of the character class like there is in regex", not your comment. But point taken about "standard". :)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, while not strictly part of the SQL-92 standard, MSSQL supports basic character classes in LIKE patterns, has for a *very* long time, and it has nothing to do with regex per se.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179859(v=sql.90).aspx

Other databases, including DB2, Informix, and MySQL, have custom language elements to support even more complex regular expressions, just not using the LIKE operator.

Comment: @richardtallent: I understand that most (all?) DBMS support full regex expressions. My point is, that this should not be confused with the (standard) `LIKE` operator which defines a completely different type of "pattern matching"

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE field BETWEEN 1 AND 999;
```

---

**EDIT:** *This will work in PostgreSQL only.*

If you're looking for a regexp pattern to match strings, then something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE field ~ '[1-9][0-9]{1,2}';
```

Check out documentation on [regexp patterns](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-matching.html#FUNCTIONS-POSIX-REGEXP).

SQL Server doesn't support regular expressions *as-is*.
You can use the following [workaround](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlclr/archive/2005/06/29/regex.aspx) or this question: [Regular Expressions in SQL Server servers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/267921/regular-expressions-in-sql-server-servers).

Comment: @ARZ, that is SQL, you'll have to be *far* more specific.

Comment: 1: He clearly says MSSQL. 2: Your 1st link is broken and is from 2005. -- Which only leaves StackEx link. This is not an answer but a link.

Comment: @bshea MSSQL requirement was added in edit (after this answer has been posted)

Comment: @barbsan Then they should ask OP to improve question before posting a specific answer to a non-specific question. It's not that hard. "This will work in PostgreSQL only."??