# SQL Server regular expression constraint

Tags: sql-server, regex, sql-server-2008

I create a table by query below

```
CREATE TABLE testing(
    test_field VARCHAR(20) CHECK(test_field like '^[a-zA-z0-9]{6,20}$')
);
```

the regular expression is working in Javascript and the table was successfully created, but when I trying to execute the insert query below, the error occurred.

```
INSERT INTO testing VALUES('abcde12345');
```

The error message is listing below

> The INSERT statement conflicted with the CHECK constraint "CK_*testing*_test_field__173876EA". The conflict occurred in database "TEST", table "dbo.testing", column 'test_field'.

Is there any difference between using Regular Expression in Javascript and SQL Server?

Any pro can help???

Comment: See article here: http://blogs.lessthandot.com/index.php/DataMgmt/DBProgramming/sql-server-does-support-regular-expressi

Comment: David, as far as I can see that just checks with a `LIKE` wildcard expression and their use case is simple enough for that. This one isn't.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/267921/regular-expressions-in-sql-server-servers Not sure if you are actually activating the regex feature, though.

Comment: @Joey: yes, this is just an article to complement your own answer.

Comment: So far, I've only found one DBE that supports posix regex constraints and it is Oracle (Reference: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35157662/is-there-a-database-engine-that-allows-for-queriable-field-constraint-specified). MS SQL and DB2 look like they have their own wildcard variant, which is unfortunate as you loose consistency of constraints between layers :(

Comment: Relevant QA on the DBA site... https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/266438/3690

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41781977/regex-for-mssql-check-constraint

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[`LIKE` does not use regular expressions.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179859.aspx)

You can add regular expression support to SQL Server by creating your own functions. One method via .NET is detailed in [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163473.aspx).

In your case you can also try the following, but it's not pretty:

```
   test_field LIKE '[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9]'
OR test_field LIKE '[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9]'
OR test_field LIKE '[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9]'
OR test_field LIKE '[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9]'
OR test_field LIKE '[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9]'
OR test_field LIKE '[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9]'
OR test_field LIKE '[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9]'
OR test_field LIKE '[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9]'
OR test_field LIKE '[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9]'
OR test_field LIKE '[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9]'
OR test_field LIKE '[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9]'
OR test_field LIKE '[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9]'
OR test_field LIKE '[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9]'
OR test_field LIKE '[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9]'
OR test_field LIKE '[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9]'
```

Comment: then what should i do if i want to add an regex in constrant？

Answer (score 1):

There's a workaround for this. Since you want to check every character, you can generate the regex with replicate:

```
SET @pattern = replicate('[a-zA-Z0-9]', LEN(@VAL));
```

This is a full function around this hack:

```
create function dbo.example (@VAL varchar(32))
RETURNS bit
WITH EXECUTE AS CALLER
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @pattern varchar(512);
    SET @pattern = replicate('[a-zA-Z0-9]', LEN(@VAL));
    IF @VAL like @pattern
    BEGIN
        RETURN 1;
    END;
    RETURN 0;
END;
GO
```

Answer (score 0):

Sql Server does not support [POSIX regular expressions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#POSIX), but only a subset.

See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179859.aspx) for details.

Comment: `LIKE` expressions are not a subset of any regex flavour. They work differently (i.e. the whole concepts of tokens and quantifiers is absent).

Comment: LIKE pattern can use wildcards that matches "Any string of zero or more characters.", "Any single character within the specified range ([a-f]) or set ([abcdef])", "Any single character not within the specified range ([^a-f]) or set ([^abcdef])". IMHO this is a subset of regex character set and braket expressions.

Comment: The wildcards `%` and `_` can be represented in regular expressions with `.*` or `.` but especially the former has a single meaning in wildcards whereas it's a token with a quantifier in regex. To me that's two very different concepts (yes, the bracket expressions are identical). Of course wildcards can describe a set of languages that is a subset of regular languages, but that doesn't mean the language used to describe them is a subset of regular expressions. IN my eyes it's not because it uses very different syntax (and even different metacharacters).

Answer (score 0):

Another way in tsql besides creating own functions is to create an XML Schema with a pattern constraint containing the regex:

```
CREATE XML SCHEMA COLLECTION dbo.RegexValidatorSchema
AS '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified"
           elementFormDefault="qualified"
           xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xs:element name="test">
        <xs:simpleType>
            <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                <xs:pattern value="^[a-zA-z0-9]{6,20}$"/>
            </xs:restriction>
        </xs:simpleType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>';
```

and add a check constraint so inserts/updates are validated:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.testing
 ADD CONSTRAINT CK_ValidateValueMatchesPattern 
 CHECK (CAST(ISNULL('<test>' + REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(Value, '&','&amp;'), '<','&lt;'), '>','&gt;') + '</test>','') AS XML(dbo.RegexValidatorSchema)) IS NOT NULL)
```

but be aware of performance degradation.