# How to check attribute in SQL Server 2012 using regular expressions?

Tags: sql, sql-server, regex, constraints

I need to insert an equipment model code, is a string formatted as:

AAA-0123456

It has to be, 3 uppercase letters, the "-" in the middle and 6 numbers,
I need to have a constraint check (model code like regular expression) I think.

How can I do this?

Comment: @siyual it says sqlserver 2012 in the title, so I guess T-Sql ?

Comment: this was already discussed. see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11223245/sql-server-regular-expression-constraint

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would do this via a check constraint, see here: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_check.asp

Yes you can put regex in a check constraint, here is an example:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.PEOPLE (
name VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL
, emailaddress VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL
, CONSTRAINT PEOPLE_ck_validemailaddress CHECK ( dbo.RegExValidate( emailaddress, N'^([\w-\.]+)@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.)|(([\w-]+\.)+))([a-zA-Z]{2,4}|[0-9]{1,3})(\]?)$' ) = 1 )
)
```

Your regular expression would be: `[A-Z][A-Z][A-Z][-][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]`

Here is a great tool to build and test reg expr http://www.regexr.com/

Comment: I think he was asking if and how can you put regex in constraints.

Comment: He needs `[A-Z][A-Z][A-Z][-][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]`