# Regex for MsSQL check constraint

Tags: sql-server, constraints

I am trying to make a column level check constraint on a table I have. I want values being inserted into the columns to be checked and made sure they're only character.

For example `values ('hello','there')` would pass, but `values ('h3llo','th3r3')` would not.

I can get it to work for a specific amount of characters (see table below), but I want to make it dynamic.

I have tried `^[a-zA-Z]+$` as well, but that doesn't seem to work either.

The simple table layout is below.

```
CREATE TABLE owner
  (
     owner_id        ID IDENTITY(1, 1) PRIMARY KEY,
     owner_firstname FIRSTNAME,
     owner_lastname  LASTNAME,
     CONSTRAINT firstname_cc CHECK (owner_firstname LIKE '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z]'),
     CONSTRAINT lastname_cc CHECK (owner_lastname LIKE '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z]')
  );
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SQL Server `LIKE` syntax does not accept regular expressions.

You can use `check (owner_firstname not like '%[^A-Z]%')`.

This constraint rejects any value containing a character not in the range `A-Z`.

You don't need to also specify `a-z` except if you are on a case sensitive collation.

Comment: When attempting this, and trying to insert the following

insert into owner
values('TEST','LOL'); 

I get the following error still 
**Msg 547, Level 16, State 0, Line 1
The INSERT statement conflicted with the CHECK constraint "firstname_cc". The conflict occurred in database "alcromer", table "dbo.owner", column 'owner_firstname'.
The statement has been terminated.**

Comment: @RoflWaffle17 - that statement works fine http://rextester.com/NFYXQ38880

Comment: It doesn't seem to be working for me..... I literally copy and pasted your code from the above link. I'm running the following version also, Microsoft SQL Server 2012 (SP3-GDR) (KB3194721) - 11.0.6248.0 (X64) 
 Sep 23 2016 15:49:43 
 Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation
 Enterprise Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.2 <X64> (Build 9200: ) (Hypervisor)

Comment: @RoflWaffle17 - is your datatype `char`? If so you will need to `RTRIM` it or alter the pattern to allow spaces.

Comment: @RoflWaffle17 - See comment above. `char` will be automatically padded with trailing spaces which your question states should be disallowed. Though best would be to change to `varchar` - names aren't fixed length.

Comment: yes - they are char(). Okay - I will change them to varchar() and see if it works

Comment: Changing from char() data type to varchar() fixed the issue! Thank you so much, @Martin Smith