# Sql search and update based on full word

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, search

I want to find a word in one of my columns and replace it with some custom text. I have the following table:

```
DECLARE @Table TABLE ( [Names] VARCHAR(100) )

INSERT INTO @Table
SELECT 'This is test module for testing' UNION
SELECT 'This is test module for to fork' UNION
SELECT 'This is test module for testing mod' UNION
SELECT 'This is testing' UNION
SELECT 'This is module'
```

I am explaining below what I need exactly:

When a user searches for the text "test" and wants to replace it with "customtext", the following rows should be selected:

```
This is test module for testing
This is test module for to fork
This is test module for testing mod
```

and after replacing the "test" (full word) with "customtext" the updated records should be:

```
This is customtext module for testing
This is customtext module for to fork
This is customtext module for testing mod
```

As you might have noticed **I need search to be done on full word not on partial text** like 'testing' in above case which contains partial text "test" in it.

Another example to explain the same requirement:

When a user searches for "mod" and wants to replace it with "customtext", the following row should be selected:

```
This is test module for testing mod
```

and after replacement with "customtext" the updated record should be:

```
This is test module for testing customtext
```

Since "mod" is full word it is the word which is replaced and not the word "module" which contains partial text "mod" in it.

Comment: When you search for `test` why is this row not returned - `This is test module for testing mod`

Comment: Right, that is to be returned too, question updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using `like`: with some pattern with my own sample data. First and formost you may add two **variables** for the word you want to **replace** as well as for the word that you want to **search**.

### * [SQLFIDDLE DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ba60d/1)

Sample data table:

```
VNAME
smp tests farms
hellocoles
hell testing str
Anvil test NSW
```

Query:

```
select vname from 
vendor 
where '.' + vname + '.' 
LIKE '%[^a-z]test[^a-z]%'
;
```

Results:

```
VNAME
Anvil test NSW
```

Here is the update query:

```
update vendor
set vname = replace(vname,'test','newword')
from vendor 
where '.' + vname + '.' 
LIKE '%[^a-z]test[^a-z]%'
;
```

### * [Before and after update query DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/fd85e/1)

- [with after update results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/fd85e/2)

  VNAME
  smp tests farms
  hellocoles
  hell testing str
  Anvil newword NSW

Comment: @RockySingh please give this a try and comment :)

Comment: this pattern doesn't seem to work for the given data? http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f6934/2

Comment: @MarkD please check here, what is not working? http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/aae7b/1 ;)

Comment: I think problem is that one cannot `REPLACE()` on a pattern, only a literal.

Comment: Thanks, it worked!. Just curious why you added '.' in where clause 
'.' + vname + '.'

Comment: @RockySingh check on [this sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/03ffc/1) it shows the use of `.` to wrap the column string as well as the full explanation of the regex.

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE TABLE_NAME
SET Column_NameA = replace(Column_NameA, 'test', 'customtext')
WHERE  (Column_NameA LIKE ('%' + ' ' + 'test' + ' ' + '%'))
```

Comment: I don't think this will work when a word you are seeking to replace is the last in the phrase?

Answer (score 0):

My solution;

```
DECLARE @Find VARCHAR(50) = 'test',
        @Replace VARCHAR(50) = 'customtext'
DECLARE @Table TABLE ( [Names] VARCHAR(100) )

INSERT INTO @Table
SELECT 'This is test module for testing' UNION
SELECT 'This is test module for to fork' UNION
SELECT 'This is test module for testing mod' UNION
SELECT 'This is testing' UNION
SELECT 'This is module'

SELECT *
    ,REPLACE(' ' + Names + ' ', ' ' + @Find + ' ', ' ' + @Replace + ' ')

FROM @Table
```

Answer (score -3):

Can you use simple regexp like (^|\s)text($|\s), or I don't undertand the problem?

Comment: I am not sure SQL allows the regexp. Do you have some reference for the same?

Comment: @NB13 I believe MySQL and Oracle support `REGEX`. SQL Server does not.

Comment: You can use regex with MS SQL Server .. but it requires a bit of integration to be done with .NET, For example: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163473.aspx . Also --- this related Q: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/267921/regular-expressions-in-sql-server-servers

Comment: This is true, CLR's can be very handy. But the solutions are not considered easy to implement and maintain.

Comment: Thanks for comments, yes I'm using mysql where it is supportable feature

Comment: OP is using SQL Server, where it is not.