# Regular expression in SQL Server 2005+

Tags: sql-server, regex, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

I am stuck with a regular expression in SQL server 2005+, i.e. I need a regular expression to validate a first name (which allows only alphabets,whitespaces and a .(dot)).

I tried with below query

```
SELECT PATINDEX('%[A-Z]%[a-z]%[.]%','John H. Wilson') as VALIDFIRSTNAME
```

But, this also fails in some cases. I'm unable to find a clear regular expression. Any assistance would be very much appreciated.

I have used patindex to recognise the given pattern. If the string doesn't match the pattern, then It should give 0 else it should give 1 or >1.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: SQL Server still doesn't have RegEx support unless you go down the CLR route. I'm unclear from your example what you're actually trying to allow - maybe if you could add some more examples of valid and invalid names we could glean more meaning from them.

Comment: (to those who answer , does sql2012 supports full regex ?)

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever : I have used patindex to recognise the given pattern. If the string doesn't match the pattern, then It should give 0 else it should give 1 or >1

Comment: @pavan6e - I know what `PATINDEX` does. What I don't understand is what you're trying to do. You've given *one* example, and you've not even said if it's meant to match or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't match mentioned condition with [available patterns](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187489%28v=sql.105%29.aspx).
Try to follow [this way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/267921/regular-expressions-in-sql-server-servers).

Comment: I have used patindex to recognise the given pattern. If the string doesn't match the pattern, then It should give 0 else it should give 1 or >1

Comment: `SELECT PATINDEX('%[A-Z]%[a-z]%[.]%','1J^oh!2n _-H.3 (W)il4son') as VALIDFIRSTNAME`

Comment: I mean that wildcard '%'allows any string of zero or more characters and because you use it - you cannot avoid non-valid characters as you described.